# C# How can I alter this code to allow users to enter a decimal (3.0, 2.5, etc.)?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# so please be gentle! I am writing a simplified GPA calculator using a sentinel controlled loop. It works so far, but I would like for users to be able to enter grades with decimal points (for example 2.3 or 3.5) and also still be able to enter numbers without decimal points. Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!
Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal gradeTotal = 0;
        int[] score = new int[100];
        string inValue;
        int scoreCnt = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("When entering grades, use a 0-4 scale. Remember; 
        A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter grade {0}: ((X to exit)) ", scoreCnt + 1);
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        gradeTotal += decimal.Parse(inValue);

        while (inValue != "X")
        {
            if (int.TryParse(inValue, out score[scoreCnt]) == false)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid data -" + "0 stored in array");
            ++scoreCnt;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter grade {0}: ((X to exit)) ", scoreCnt + 
            1);
            inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (inValue == "X") break;
            gradeTotal += decimal.Parse(inValue); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The number of scores: " + scoreCnt);
        Console.WriteLine("Your grade total is: " + gradeTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("Your GPA is: {0:0.00}", gradeTotal / scoreCnt); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using a double instead of an int

Comment: `int[] score = new int[100];`. How do you expect users to input floating point values (values with a decimal point) when you're storing them in an `int` array?

Comment: Thank you Ken! Changed it to float and it works!

Comment: 1) Parse only once to an exact variable e.g.: `decimal score; bool success = decimal.TryParse(inValue, out score);`  Then you can re-use the result without parsing it again.  2) Always parse to the right type.  For you that's `double` or `decimal`.  In 2 places you parse as `decimal` in another as `int`.  So it seems you partly know but need to be consistent.  (like don't mix float and decimal) 3) `int[] score` doesn't even seem to get used.  Don't keep around useless variables you aren't going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to enter numbers with decimal points, then you need to use a type that supports decimal points, like a `decimal` (like you are already doing for the `gradeTotal`). To do this, you'd need to change how you parse and store the user input, by changing `int` to `decimal` in a couple of places:

```
decimal[] score = new decimal[100];

if (decimal.TryParse(inValue, out score[scoreCnt]) == false)
```

But there are a few other changes you need to make as well. When we say `gradeTotal += decimal.Parse(inValue);`, we will get an exception if the user input a non-numeric string. We want to avoid exceptions, so we should use `TryParse` instead, as we're already doing in our `if` condition.

In fact, we can re-use some of the code we already have, by entering the `while` loop earlier, and using the `TryParse` that's already there.

Also, why should we store any data (zeros) in our array if the input was invalid? We can just store it in a temp variable first, and only add it to our array if it's valid. Also, we should remember that there is invalid data other than non-numeric input. We can add some additional conditions to ensure the number is between 0 and 4.

A couple of other things we can remove are the `gradeTotal` and `scoreCnt` variables. We can always get the total by summing up the items in our array, and the score count by using the count of items in our array (assuming we don't add invalid items).

And, for that matter, why use an array at all? A `List<decimal>` is simpler because we don't have to declare any set size before hand. In the current implementation, we are limited to 100 entries, including invalid ones.

Here's some code that incorporates these changes:

```
var scores = new List<decimal>();

Console.WriteLine("When entering grades, use a 0-4 scale. Remember:");
Console.WriteLine("A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0\n");

Console.Write("Enter grade 1 (or 'X' to exit): ");
var inValue = Console.ReadLine();

while (inValue.ToUpper() != "X")
{
    decimal input;

    if (!decimal.TryParse(inValue, out input) || input < 0 || input > 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid data; enter a number from 0 to 4, or 'X' to exit."); 
    }
    else
    {
        scores.Add(input);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter grade {0} (or 'X' to exit): ", scores.Count + 1);
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("The number of scores: " + scores.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Your grade total is: " + scores.Sum());
Console.WriteLine("Your GPA is: {0:0.00}", scores.Average());

Console.ReadLine();
```